# How do I use JOIN to query mysql from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this code on my game script (php). This checks if the player has a vehicle equipped, and that it still exists. My code:

```
if ($rs[vehicle] != 0) {
    $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id='$rs[vehicle]'", $db);
     if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result2) == 0) { mysql_query("UPDATE mobsters SET vehicle = 0 WHERE id ='$id'"); }
}
```

I want to edit this code so that if it does exist, it will also check the `db_vehicles` table and find out details of the said vehicle (name, speed etc). A sloppy way of doing that is:

```
if ($rs[vehicle] != 0) {
    $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id='$rs[vehicle]'", $db);
     if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result2) == 0) {
         mysql_query("UPDATE mobsters SET vehicle = 0 WHERE id ='$id'"); 
         } else {
         $ = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2); 
         $sql_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_vehicles WHERE id='$[type]'", $db);
         $ = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result3);
         $name = $[name]; $speed = $[speed];
         }
     }
```

Obviously I'd like to do this with a JOIN to use as few queries as possible. What kind of join should I use?

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injections; please use PDO and prepared queries instead.

Comment: i dont understand what that means

Answer (score 1):

Your code should use only one select statement and another for update, this is the select with join:

```
$sql_result3 = mysql_query("Select dbv.Name, dbv.speed, dbv.type 
                            from db_Vehicles dbv inner join vehicles v 
                             on v.id = dbv.id  WHERE dbv.id='$rs2[type]'"
                            , $db);
```

BTW as @mc10 said your code is prone to sql injection so you will find alot of stuff here in SO about how to prevent it like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282678/php-mysql-join-queryy) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: and then `if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result3) == 0) { mysql_query("UPDATE mobsters SET vehicle = 0 WHERE id ='$id'"); }` ??

Comment: Yes, you can't do the two things in one statement so you need two distinct sql statements.